# C++ code generation (size) between VC6 and VC11

Tags: c++, size, visual-c++-6

I've an application .. (console based Win32 , about 5 different classes)
Quite small app.

Compiled it with VC11 - resulting application were about 79kb 
Last night compiled it with VC6 ...came out 204kb .. ok no biggy
Then i added few functions ...
VC11 - resulted in 69kb 
and VC6 dropped to 112kb

both sizes of cause "Release" no debug info included 
but this change in size just breaks my mind ... wat?... how ? why ?

No strings were added or removed
no definitions changed ... 
Just couple of new functions .... (in assembler it would be no more than 50 bytes extra - including all push&pops)

Does VC actually compresses executables ? or ? 
How is this change actually possible ? ... and if there is that hidden overhead - how i can get rid of it permanently ?

Comment: It could be optimization (e.g. [function inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion)...) Or some kind of [strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strip_(Unix))ing. You should not bother. Study the generated assembler code if you care that much.

Comment: Thing is ... that this behavior seems to be random ... even adding removing space in the code may result in increase size by 100% decrease by 50% (in my case of my small app)

What is it exactly ?... what is MS putting into the executable ?

Comment: But why does it matter to you? You should **edit your question** to explain and motivate it

Comment: I'm just curious whats goes into my exe 
Those fluctuations in size really bugging me ... what is it ? ..since its not an debug build ..what the hell is it ? And why it behave like a ghost ...now its there and next build its not ....